# Respawn MySQL on Ubuntu? Server ran out of memory, killed MySQL & Apache, MySQL didn't respawn

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, upstart

Just as above, I increased the RAM (it's a VM), but that doesn't give me a safety net.
I was under the impression by default it should respawn, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

*Ubuntu 10.04

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://askubuntu.com/a/451889)

Answer (score 1):

Credit from: https://askubuntu.com/a/451889

#### Create a script to check status and start if not found:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
    then
        /usr/sbin/service mysql start
    fi
```

#### Make sure script is executable:

```
    chmod +x /path/to/script
```

#### Finally create a cron to run the script:

```
    sudo crontab -e
```

#### And add (one of) the following lines to the crontab:

```
    */1 * * * * /path/to/script  ### Every Minute
    */5 * * * * /path/to/script  ### Every 5 minutes
    */10 * * * * /path/to/script ### Every 10 minutes
    */30 * * * * /path/to/script ### Every 30 minutes
    0 * * * * /path/to/script    ### Every hour

 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

You can set the cron to be whatever time works for you, I just gave more example times than the original post did, in case you would like some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I may do this.  I was hoping someone had a suggestion using upstart or adjusting an existing script.  It's just so strange Apache will respawn, but MySQL wont (as defaults).

Comment: @ShawnKhameneh This might be more reliable than upstart. I have seen quite a few threads about problems with upstart starting MySQL. But either way, glad to help.

Comment: Interesting, I had some issues with upstart and Node respawns.  Upstart wont respawn if the process has exit status 0.

Answer (score 0):

The setting of the spawn for the mysql is located at `/etc/init/mysql.conf`. Please check your log as well to solve the real problem instead of temporary solution of keep restarting the mysql server. Usually, the log file for mysql is in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

To change the max number of tries to respawn, change the respawn value in `/etc/init/mysql.conf`

You will see a line with these pattern:

```
 respawn 

 # Try to respawn for max try of two with five seconds interval
 respawn limit 2 5
```